# CMAKE : How to put absolute path in include directories

Tags: cmake

First, I am sorry if the question has been answered but I couldn't find any solution.

I am trying to compile a simple program with cmake. *But I can't seem to include absolute paths.*

My project (located in `C:/path/to/my/project` for the understanding) is simple with an `include` directory with header files. However, I must include another directory ***completely*** somewhere else.

My `include_directories` looks like this:

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" "C:/path/to/my/other/directory/include")
```

However when I do :

```
get_property(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(dir ${dirs})
  message(STATUS "dir='${dir}'")
endforeach()
```

To check my include directories I have the following answer:

```
-- dir='/c/path/to/my/project/include'
-- dir='/c/path/to/my/project/C:/path/to/my/other/directory/include'
```

So `cmake` interprets the paths as relative to my project folder.
How can I **force** `cmake` to interpret them as absolute ?

I am using `cmake v3.17.3`.

---

**EDIT**

I have tried doing so but it doesn't seem to work either since the path is not appended to the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property of my target.

```
add_executable(app src1.c src2.c)
target_include_directories(app BEFORE PRIVATE "C:/path/to/my/other/directory/include")
```

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some research the answer is :

```
add_executable(app src1.c src2.c)
target_include_directories(app BEFORE PRIVATE "/C/path/to/my/other/directory/include")
```

The path I was referring to was wrong since I am on `msys`. Therefore `c:/` should become `/c/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write the path as:

```
add_executable(app src1.c src2.c)
target_include_directories(app BEFORE PRIVATE "C:\\path\\to\\my\\other\\directory\\include")
```